# Service worker errors when restarted only in chrome: Failed to load the script unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

### Problem

- On Firefox the below service worker can be installed, and stopped and started fine.
- On Chrome, the below test service worker install fines, works perfectly until one closes and opens the browser, or in the SW dev tools clicks stop and then click start.

### Intro

I created a service worker, debugged it with chrome on local and it worked fine. I deployed it to a website, and I see the errors in the image below (only in Chrome, with Firefox its working fine):

```
/static/core.jslib/sw.min.js:1 Failed to load the script unexpectedly
/static/core.jslib/sw.min.js:1 Failed to load the script unexpectedly
```

With chrome if I click start the service worker it immediately stops. With Firefox it runs awhile before stopping (expected).

### Environment

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04, and on Windows 10
- Browsers

  - Chrome: Version 97.0.4692.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)
  - Also occurs on Chromium 92.0.451598
- Its not in offline mode on Chrome under `Network` or `Application`
- The only clue I have is the first time the SW installs, its works fine. But then if I close the browser and reopen it, I see these errors and the SW stops. Sound like a global state issue, whereby variable/object arent present when worker starts up again, however I don't have any global state, as you can see, just a few functions.
- No extensions, all disabled
- Tried on 2 different computers,
- The sw.min.js below is not minified, but pasted in unminified.

[image]

I have simplified my service worker down to this, so now I am quite sure its not my code, but something chromium is doing:

```js
/ INSTALL -------
async function install() {
    console.log("SW: Installing ...");
}
async function handleInstall(event) {
    event.waitUntil(install());
}
self.addEventListener("install", handleInstall);

// ACTIVATE -------
async function activate() {
    console.log("SW: Activated");
}
async function handleActivate(event) {
    event.waitUntil(activate());
}
self.addEventListener("activate", handleActivate);

// FETCH -------
async function swFetch(event) {
    //console.log('SW: FETCH - RELEASE TIMESTAMP', RELEASE_TIMESTAMP)
    const response = await fetch(event.request);
    console.log("SW: FETCHED ", event.request.url);
    return response
}
async function handleFetch(event) {
    return event.respondWith(swFetch(event));
}
self.addEventListener("fetch", handleFetch);
```

Note: When it works, the sw.min.js file appears under sources (when it installs), close and open the browser again and then this is not shown:
[image]

PS Running on Ubuntu 20.04. Maybe its to do with where it stores the Service workers in linux.

I even added a fetch call to get the file and print it out just before it registeres the service work to verify it can access the file, and it always is okay:

```
Fetched /static/core.jslib/sw.min.js 
Responsebody: (...)bodyUsed: falseheaders: Headers {}ok: trueredirected: falsestatus: 200statusText: ""type: "basic"url: "https://www.demo..../static/core.jslib/sw.min.js"[[Prototype]]: Response
swregister.min.50eb376e2ddc.js:1 SW: Registered - At scope https://www.demo..../
/static/core.jslib/sw.min.js:1 Failed to load the script unexpectedly
/static/core.jslib/sw.min.js:1 Failed to load the script unexpectedly
```

### Error Order

The strange thing is, the error appears as one clicks to navigate elsewhere. The console log below was generated as follows:

1. Cleared the console.
2. Then clicked a link
3. The error was shown immediately
4. Then it shows the note about navigating
5. Then it registered the service worker.

So I don't thing its a fetch issue, I think its internal storage of the service worker file, that chrome can't access.

[image]

### Chrome Service worker internals

```
chrome://serviceworker-internals/` shows the service worker:
Scope: https://www.demo..../
Registration ID: 287
Navigation preload enabled: false
Navigation preload header length: 4
Active worker:
Installation Status: ACTIVATED
Running Status: STOPPED
Fetch handler existence: EXISTS
Script: https://www.demo..../static/core.jslib/sw.min.js
Version ID: 649
Renderer process ID: 0
Renderer thread ID: -1
DevTools agent route ID: -2
Log:
```

And if I click `start` it shows:

```
Console: {"lineNumber":0,"message":"Failed to load the script unexpectedly",
"message_level":3,"sourceIdentifier":1,"sourceURL":"https://www.demo.../static/core.jslib/sw.min.js"}
```

Whereas other peoples service workers start and run for awhile.

### Response Headers

Here are the response headers for `sw.min.js`

```
# Here are the response headers for:
date: Tue, 25 Jan 2022 18:15:44 GMT
etag: "61f03d46-350"
last-modified: Tue, 25 Jan 2022 18:11:18 GMT
server: notepad.exe
service-worker-allowed: /
```

### Manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Cube",
    "short_name": "Cube",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/static/core.pwa/img/android-chrome-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any"
        },
        {
            "src": "/static/core.pwa/img/android-chrome-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any"
        },
        {
            "src": "/static/core.pwa/img/maskable_icon.png",
            "sizes": "1024x1024",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable"
        }
    ],
    "theme_color": "#212121",
    "background_color": "#ffffff",
    "display": "standalone",
    "start_url": "/"
}
```

Comment: Do you still have the problem with a fresh Chrome profile? Could it be coming from one of your extensions?

Comment: Same problem with fresh install

Comment: I'm attempting to recreate your error, in the meantime maybe this will be helpful: https://www.chromium.org/blink/serviceworker/service-worker-faq?

Comment: I found an interesting thread related to your issue: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/lLb3EJzjw0o

Comment: Thanks for the link @Puka, and thanks for trying to replicate it. Out of interest which OS did you try it on?

Comment: I borrowed someones windows computer, and was the same, so don't worry about OS question

Comment: Please add your answer as a separate answer below, don't edit it into your question.

Comment: @double-beep, was just a quick update to let people know not to waste thier time while i confirmed exactly what was the issue that resolved it, and was also under a lot of time pressure, so I planned to convert it to an answer.

Comment: This is not expected behavior. Can you share a complete manifest?

Comment: @ChrisCashwell Please see the added last section, is that what you require?

Comment: got the same problem, i had a empty sw.js that did absolut nothing, stop/starting it works fine when it isn't of type=module. See now that i also using charset...

Comment: Did you find anyway to catch the error in any error handler?

Comment: @Endless, no I didnt, as you can see by the bug report, it seems to happen when Chrome is loading the service worker from its storage, my guess is since its an error the C++ code, you not going to catch it with JavaScript. Wh not just disable the charset for your sw.js file.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

The folks at Chromium figured out it was the MIME content type header:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1292379#c17

In nginx I changed the header from :

- `content-type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8`

to

- `content-type: application/javascript`

Now it works!

### Original Answer

When registering the service worker, I set the type as module. Apparently it means "crash when restarted" in Chrome.

```
const options = {
    scope: "/",
    // type: "module",  <-- needed to comment this out
};
const result = await navigator.serviceWorker.register(swPath, options);
```

Apparently Chrome does not seem to support module type service workers, when I checked the support table, there seemed to be good support.